# Where can I find the Angular `ViewContainerRef` source code?

Tags: angular

I've been trying to find the source code from angular github, but I was unable to find it. Can someone point me the one?

[view_container_ref](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/linker/view_container_ref.ts) only has function name, I want to know how the ViewContainerRef method is implemented not how to use it, like the ViewContainerRef method createEmbeddedView what's inside.

Comment: https://netbasal.com/angular-2-understanding-viewcontainerref-acc183f3b682 read the doc for  `ViewContainerRef` with example

Comment: Hello. I want to know how the `ViewContainerRef` method is implemented and not how to use it, like the` ViewContainerRef` method `createEmbeddedView` what's inside.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the source code of `ViewContainerRef` [on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/linker/view_container_ref.ts)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it can only see the function name, can't see how the method is implemented.

Comment: if you open your vs code and start to implement viewConfainerRef there will be import at the top so you can press command + click or alt + click to go inside that type def file and view source code, note: you must not change this files

Comment: I down load the source code from angular github, but cannot find the functon details in `ViewContainerRef`  definition file, I don't understand that's why. Your method can see the compiled source code, but do not see the specific implementation method.